# In what way(s) is the wasmi project used in Substrate/Polkadot?

Tags: wasmi

What is the purpose of using wasmi in Substrate/Polkadot?

Would it also be possible to use the wasmer project instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are to ways in which `wasmi` is used within substrate:

**Execution of the runtime:**
The state transition function of a substrate based chain is defined in terms of wasm code that is hosted in chain state itself. This allows for easy and forkless upgrades of the blockchain logic. For this reason there is a `wasmi` interpreter included in each node in order to execute the runtime. That said, these days we use `wasmtime` by default to execute the runtime. You could still use `wasmi` by supplying `--wasm-execution interpreted-i-know-what-i-do`. However, this it not advised because it is way too slow to keep up with the network.

**Execution of wasm contracts:** `pallet-contracts` which is part of FRAME (substrate's runtime authoring framework) is a wasm contract platform. Currently, it uses `wasmi` in order to interpret those contracts. Since contracts are untrusted as opposed to the runtime we can't use `wasmtime` which is subject to compiler bombs. Using `wasmer-singlepass` is something we are looking into for contracts. As a matter of fact you could run your contracts with wasmer today by supplying `--feature wasmer-sandbox` when compiling a substrate node. This is still highly experimental, though.